# How do I validate a model object inside a model object in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use MVC3 Model Validation, but I'm getting stumped when I have an object inside my model.

```
public class PersonalInformationViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public string StreetAddress {get;set;}

    public string City {get;set;}

    public string Country {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string PostalCode {get;set;}
}
```

Right now If I don't fill in name, ModelState will say its invalid, but if I fill in the name and not the street address the ModelState is valid.

Whats the best way to accomplish proper validation this way?

Answer (score 3):

Mark the outer `Address` property as `[Required]`.

Comment: Okay, but what id there are a few fields on the address.

Comment: I see whats going on. The address has an associated partial. And this code is not firing on the partial.
The Html.ValidationStyleClassFor(x => x.State, "line", "error")

Comment: Does `State` have `[Required]`?

Comment: What happened was the ModelState had "BusinessAddress.State" as the key, but the _partial was looking for "State" in the ModelState. I temporaly solved the problem by copying like this: ModelState["State"] = ModelState["BusinessAddress.State"]